# How to install Rsymphony package in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: r, redhat

I am trying to install the package `Rsymphony` in a remote Red Hat Linux server. But I am encountering the following error:

```
installing *source* package ‘Rsymphony’ ... 
Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
See  <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’
```

It seems I need to install the symphony libraries and headers in Linux before I can install `Rsymphony`.

Comment: Yes, you need. Please proceed. The [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsymphony/index.html) clearly says **SystemRequirements:  SYMPHONY libraries and headers**

Comment: Well, that's where I am stuck at.

Comment: So http://superuser.com/ might be useful

Answer (score 0):

The Bioconductor package `lpsymphony` is easier to install; the description says:

```
The main difference between this package and Rsymphony is that it 
includes the solver source code (SYMPHONY version 5.6), while Rsymphony 
expects to find header and library files on the users' system. Thus the 
intention of lpsymphony is to provide an easy to install interface to
SYMPHONY.
```

A hint to `lpsymphony` will be included in a next version of the optimisation task view.